# JS files not loaded (intermittent)

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm seeing errors from clients (reported in bugsnag) very occasionally where it seems some JS file or other hasn't loaded. A later file which then depends on the earlier one being there will error. Usually with a 'React is not defined' or similar problem.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Some things I've tested for

- I've switched form hosting the majority of the files myself to getting them from popular CDNs so have eliminated problems with my server set up.
- I can confirm it's not always the same file, or even a file from the same public CDN. It just seems that *sometimes* some files don't turn up and the browser continues as if everything is fine (until it's not)
- To be clear, this doesn't happen reliably at all, and is rare enough (once every day or two over several hundred visits to the site) I'm assuming it's not limited to a single browser.